Dynamics 365 Ribbon Diff Xml Error which contains dependency
In our production environment I have done 4 managed deployment successfully afterwards when I tried to do a publish all it showed me an error related to RibbonDif Xml file.
the error is:
"The dependent component RibbonDiff (Id=2696d106-f0b9-ee11-a569-0022489ca65c) does not exist. Failure trying to associate it with RibbonDiff (Id=bf649d1d-6e15-ef11-9f89-0022489ca4d1) as a dependency. Missing dependency lookup type = PrimaryKeyLookup."
I have tried many things such as checking all the entities, checking the ribbon Dif Xml file for more than 158 custom entities with solution packager, I have tried many fetch XML queries but at the end there is no way to solve this issue.
Could you guide me how should I find this difference? how should I find which solution? which component? which entity? is involved to this error.
